# Numerical Method for Multivariate Inversion Formula

Tags: numerics, numerical-modelling, integration, r, complex-analysis

For my research, I need to evaluate the density of a random vector $\boldsymbol{X} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ using the multivariate inversion formula. Let the density function of $\boldsymbol{X}$ be $f (\boldsymbol{x})$. If the characteristic function of $\boldsymbol{X}$ is given by
$$
\phi(\boldsymbol{t}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i \boldsymbol{t}^\top \boldsymbol{x}} f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x},
$$
then using the multivariate formula,
$$
f (\boldsymbol{x}) = (2 \pi)^{-p} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i \boldsymbol{t}^\top \boldsymbol{x}} \phi (\boldsymbol{t}) d\boldsymbol{t}.
$$
In the paper of [Sheppard (1991)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3532396), there is a numerical procedure through the Riemann sums mentioned to evaluate the density function, but it is quite complicated and even gets more so for higher dimensions. Plus, given that I don't have very good knowledge of numerical methods, I am really looking for methods that are already implemented or at least not too hard to implement by myself. My working programming language is R.

I am actually aware of two R packages that can approximate the Fourier integrals: `CharFunToolR` and `fourierin`. Both of them are limited to lower $p < 3$: `CharFunToolR` only works for univariate data while `fourierin` only allows for up to bivariate now. One problem with the `fourierin` package is that it requires the upper and lower limits be real values. When I tested with some know distributions, for a given set of upper and lower limits, `fourierin` did not yield correct densities for all values (usually those in the boundary; the densities are very different from the truth). This is not convenient because the estimated densities may not be reliable.

From my search so far, I understand that this is a hard problem because we are integrating over the infinite domains and higher dimensions are numerically challenging. For that reason, I guess at this point, I am okay with dimensions within 5 (10 would be nice but I think I cannot be too greedy). Please help me if you have any ideas. Thank you so much.

Here is a code snippet regarding the multivariate normal distribution. I put here just in case it is useful somehow.

```
p <- 6

mu <- c(-0.448, -0.48, -0.661, -0.325, -0.539, -0.297)

Sigma <- matrix(nrow = p, ncol = p, c(
   0.136, -0.013,  0.001, -0.009, -0.005, 0.004,
  -0.013,  0.123,  0.050,  0.002,  0.037, 0.040,
   0.001,  0.050,  0.095, -0.011,  0.056, 0.014,
  -0.009,  0.002, -0.011,  0.099, -0.005, 0.008, 
  -0.005,  0.037,  0.056, -0.005,  0.075, 0.003, 
   0.004,  0.040,  0.014,  0.008,  0.003, 0.102
))

x <- c(0.053, 0.523, -0.041, -0.589, -0.044, -0.066)

cf <- function(tee, x, mu, Sigma) {
  exp(-1i * crossprod(tee, x)) * exp(1i * crossprod(tee, mu) - 0.5 * t(tee) %*% Sigma %*% tee)
}

mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x, mu, as.matrix(Sigma))
```

Comment: What you call the "characteristic function" just looks like the Fourier transform to me. Is that right?

Comment: What information do you have about the density $f$? Are you given a set of finite samples $\{x_i\}$ and values $\{f(x_i)\}$ and you need to estimate the characteristic function, or can you evaluate $f$ at any completely arbitrary argument $x$? If it's the latter, do you have an analytic expression for $f$? I ask because, depending on how nice you assume $f$ is (or isn't), you can construct adversarial examples that make numerical evaluation of the characteristic function basically impossible.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth yes, based on my understanding, it the Fourier transform. The R packages ``CharFunToolR`` and ``fourierin`` that I mentioned approximate the integration using fast Fourier transform. My knowledge of complex analysis is pretty limited so it is quite challenging for me to work on these.

Comment: @DanielShapero I think the density function $f$ has the support over the entire real-number line. For my research, I just have the values that I need to evaluate the densities, so not a set of finite samples $\{ \boldsymbol{x}_i \}$ and their corresponding densities $\{ f(\boldsymbol{x}_i) \}$. I only have the analytic expression for the characteristic function $\phi$ and I don't believe the density function $f$ has a closed-form. I believe it is also not possible to separate the real and imaginary parts (someone asks me to try seeing if that is the case).